# Como obtener el codigo html de una página que usa cloudflare?

Tags: php

Estoy usando la función `file_get_contents();` pero me da el código del checking de cloudflare. ¿Ese bloqueador es solo para DDOS o también para esa función de php? ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer funcionar el script?

EDIT:
El script que uso:

```
function get_page_code($url)
                    {
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
                        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        $data = curl_exec($ch);
                        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                          echo curl_error($ch);
                          echo "\n<br />";
                          $contents = '';
                        } else {
                          curl_close($ch);
                        }
                        if (!is_string($data) || !strlen($data)) {                      
                        $data = '';
                        }

                        return $data;
                    }
```

Comment: Creo que sería mejor hacer esto con [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php).

Comment: @A.Cedano en realidad lo hago con cURL pero pensé que sería lo mismo, edito el post con la función

Comment: Debe ser un problema de la URL, que requerirá un token o algo... Yo probé el código con la página de Cloudfare, y me trae el HTML a la pantalla.

Comment: Prueba con la web seriesblanco.com

Comment: Efectivamente, la página parece estar en el modo de protección contra ataque de Cloudfare, sólo muestra esto durante unos segundos: ***Checking your browser before accessing...***. Para poder hacer cURL debes contactar al propietario/administrador para que incluya tu IP en una lista blanca, de lo contrario no podrás hacer nada. [Puedes leer más detalles en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523671/5587982) (en inglés) y también puedes leer [esto en el blog de CF](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-im-under-attack-mode/).

Comment: He estado investigando y he descubierto que puedes hacerlo con las cookies que almacena la web una vez hecho el checking de seguridad, pero como puedo enviar las cookies que necesito? he probado con esto pero nada  `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, '__cfduid=d9a4e21aaf9548463dbac845752e1ad1d1517936297; cf_clearance=694d3756b43425f925ee10536c495052a14ae150-1518014540-31536000');`